# Error on Apex Trigger when trying to use "substringAfter(' ')"

Tags: apex, trigger, substring

I started this issue in another post but figured I'd separate it so that I could go into further detail here. I'm attempting to remove the city that is after the space. As an example the variable is Referral_Store__c = '2036 Chicago'.

This is the error I'm getting.

> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

This is my Apex Trigger any help would be appreciated. I highlighted the line that is causing the error.

```
public class HomeDepotStoreHandler extends TriggerHandler {   
    public HomeDepotStoreHandler() {}

    public override void beforeUpdate() {
    i360__Sale__c[] sales = (i360__Sale__c[])Trigger.new;
    i360__Sale__c a = sales[0];

    Set<String> referralStoreNames = new Set<String>();
    for (i360__Sale__c sale : sales){ 
    referralStoreNames.add(a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' '));
    }

    i360__Staff__c[] staffMembers = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                 FROM i360__Staff__c 
                                 WHERE Name IN :referralStoreNames];

    Map<String,i360__Staff__c> staffMap = new Map<String,i360__Staff__c>();
    for (i360__Staff__c staffMember : staffMembers){
    staffMap.put(staffMember.Name,staffMember);
    }  
        if (a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c == null) {
    //you will need to null check this;
        a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c = staffMap.get(a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')).Id;
        }

    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'HD Base Store Our System:' + 
    a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've used my example to attempt to bulkify the trigger - good work!

You have a bug though that you'll need to fix (that will fix your null error and make it all work properly)

Change the code just before the loop and including the loop to:

```
public override void beforeUpdate() {
    i360__Sale__c[] sales = (i360__Sale__c[])Trigger.new;

    Set<String> referralStoreNames = new Set<String>();
    for (i360__Sale__c sale : sales){ 
        if (sale.Referral_Store__c != null){
          referralStoreNames.add(sale.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' '));
        }
    }
```

You were extracting the `sale` as `a` but that was the NON bulkified version. You'll see in this version that I'm not using the `a` var, but using a `sale` var which I then null check every time in the loop.

Finally, you need a loop at the end of your code - you are again using that single instance `a`, but you should be looping through all the sales records.

Replace this:

```
    if (a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c == null) {
      a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c = staffMap.get(a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')).Id;
    }
```

With this:

```
for (i360__Sale__c sale : sales){ 
    //enter loop if one value is empty, but the store person value is not.
    if (sale.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c == null && 
        sale.Referral_Store__c != null) {
        sale.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c = staffMap.get(sale.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')).Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nathan said he's having the problem with the `staffMap.get` line, but I agree that check should definitely be in there

Comment: Yes, it should have been in both places. He's trying to bulkify the code, but there were a few problems.

Comment: Thanks so much @CasparHarmer. I at one point had the loop on the bottom, took it off thinking it was causing an issue, thanks for noticing that and the a var. Means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, `staffMap` does not contain a key of `a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')`

You're populating `staffMap` with a key of `staffMember.Name`.  Is that going to have the same value as `a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')`?

This is debuggin 101.
Do some system.debug statements outputting `staffMember.Name` and `a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ')`.
Are they exactly the same?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was able to compare the two and the a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ') was returning chicago rather than removing it. So I changed it to a.Referral_Store__c.substringBefore(' ') and now I have the numbers. Thanks so much!